# how to transcope a part of column as rows in pandas

Tags: pandas, data-science, data-analysis

i have a data of some patients and they are in a configuration that cant be used for data analysis
we have a couple of patients that each patients have multiple visits to our clinic. therefor, in our data we have a row for a visit an it contains some data and as i mentioned every patient have multiple visit. so i have multiple rows for a single patient . i would like a way that we can have just one row for a patient and multiple variables for each visit
for example

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYjCp.png)
as you can see we have multiple visits for a patient
and i wana change it to this format
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXdrl.png)

Comment: Can you provide your data as raw text please?

Comment: You probably should not be posting sensitive/confidential patient and personally identifiable information here. You might get in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pivot your dataframe:

```
out = (df.pivot_table(index=['Family Name', 'ID', 'Sex', 'age'],
                      columns = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str))
         .reset_index())
out.columns = out.columns.to_flat_index().map(''.join)
print(out)

# Output
  Family Name  ID   Sex  age  AA1  AA2   AB1  AB2   AC1  AC2   AE1  AE2
0    Mr James   2  male   64  9.0  NaN  10.0  NaN  11.0  NaN  12.0  NaN
1      Mr Lee   1  male   62  1.0  5.0   2.0  6.0   3.0  7.0   4.0  8.0
```